# Android How to update RecyclerView View from fragment Kotlin

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin

In my MainActivity I have RecyclerView and Fragment. The fragment is displayed when I click on an item from the list of RecyclerView . There I can edit some values. And when I press  button in fragment the values in RecyclerView are changing but the view is not updating. Only when I reopen Activity View is updated. How I can update RecyclerView View with the button which is inside my fragment?

Comment: Something has to call your RecyclerView adapter's `notifyDataSetChanged()`. There are a few different approaches you could use to achieve this. Depending on how much interaction you eventually want between the Activity and Fragment, a ViewModel could be a good option.

Comment: can you share your recyclerView adapter code ?? btw , to update a view at specific position you could use `adapter.notifyItemChange(position)` , to do this, you should expose the adapter position to your fragment.